# Search MySQL DATABASE For Emojis

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have next table:

```
CREATE TABLE reactionroles (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    guild_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    message_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    Emoji text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    Role bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    channel_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO reactionroles VALUES (
    60, 358548815713665034, 700820147580960789, '',
    368811874223128587, 490828235953668096
);
```

I'm trying to select a row with a specific Emoji in a MySQL table.

To show my problem I run

```
SELECT * FROM `reactionroles` WHERE Emoji = '';
```

in the phpmyadmin SQL-Query.
I expect that there will only be one result but it print's out every row, no matter what Emoji.
[SQL-Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvSEt.png)

I already set the collation to

> utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Anyone knows why this happens?

EDIT: the DDL for the table

```
CREATE TABLE reactionroles ( 
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  guild_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  message_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  Emoji text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
  Role bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  channel_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (ID) ) 
  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Please provide soma samples data for your table

Comment: And the DDL for your table. (that is, the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE relationroles`)  Please copy/paste the text, not the image....!

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev
(60, 358548815713665034, 700820147580960789, '', 368811874223128587, 490828235953668096)
And also look at the picture in my question there you can also see some data samples.

Comment: @Luuk

reactionroles | CREATE TABLE `reactionroles` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `guild_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `message_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Emoji` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Role` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Look here: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=924d75bdf8e620dc6eb60be17007626f&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57 it's work perfect

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev
Is there any way why this doesn't work for my like on the website?
Even if I create another DB just like this the same thing happens to me

Comment: @CuzImSyntax I think the problem is not the database, but the encoding you are using in your php file (or similar): you are embedding the sql in a php file with an encoding that presumably is not unicode. As a result of that, it's probable that the query being sent to the server doesn't have an emoji

Comment: I think most values from `show variables like '%character_set%';` should give 'utf8mb4', with the exception of the ones ending in \_filesystem' and '_system'.

Comment: @Luuk Ok, that could be a reason why it's not working character_set_database and character_set_server is latin1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a table with `Emoji` column as `TEXT`, so you have to cast `Emoji` as BINARY:

```
SELECT * FROM `reactionroles` WHERE CAST(Emoji AS BINARY) =  '';
```